# Weird behaviour of asyncio Queue

Tags: queue, python-3.6, python-asyncio

Why asyncio Queue is behaving so weirdly here, even though putting an item there it is showing empty?

```
In [1]: from multiprocessing import Queue

In [2]: q = Queue()

In [3]: q.empty()
Out[3]: True

In [4]: q.put(100)

In [5]: q.empty()
Out[5]: False

In [6]: from asyncio import Queue

In [7]: q = Queue()

In [8]: q.empty()
Out[8]: True

In [9]: q.put(100)
Out[9]: <generator object Queue.put at 0x7f97849bafc0>

In [10]: q.empty()
Out[10]: True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you didn't put anything:

```
q.put(100)
```

`put` here - is not a plain function, it's a [coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue.put). You [should](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) `await` it to put item in queue.

For example:

```
import asyncio
from asyncio import Queue


async def main():
    q = Queue()

    print(q.empty())  # True

    await q.put(100)

    print(q.empty())  # False


if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    finally:
        loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
        loop.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

As Mikhail Gerasimov's answer, `q.put(100)` is a `coroutine` and explaining more detail...

> Calling a coroutine does not start its code running – the coroutine
>   object returned by the call doesn’t do anything until you schedule its
>   execution. There are two basic ways to start it running: call await
>   coroutine or yield from coroutine from another coroutine (assuming the
>   other coroutine is already running!), or schedule its execution using
>   the ensure_future() function or the AbstractEventLoop.create_task()
>   method.
>
> Coroutines (and tasks) can only run when the event loop is running.

It is from [Python Coroutines doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html).

In the Mikhail Gerasimov's example,
Another `coroutine` `async def main()` calls `await` with `coroutine` `q.put(100)` and event loop is running `loop.run_until_complete(main())` such as the above description.